# What does these (response, data, error) in println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)) means in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Can anyone please tell me what does below code means. I am trying to learn swift and i didn't understand
below lines.

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) 
{
    (response, data, error) in
    println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
}
```

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This asynchronously initiates the network `request` and when it's done, it performs a `println` of the `NSString` representation of the `data` it received, and it does this the main queue (`NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()`).

In terms of deciphering it, consider the definition of the `sendAsynchronousRequest` function:

```
class func sendAsynchronousRequest(_ request: NSURLRequest,
                                 queue queue: NSOperationQueue!,
                   completionHandler handler: (NSURLResponse!,
                                              NSData!,
                                              NSError!) -> Void)
```

That third parameter is a closure. Your syntax is taking advantage of the "trailing closure" syntax, that allows you to supply that trailing closure parameter as a block after the function. And thus, the `response, data, error in` syntax is mapping those three variables to the `NSURLResponse`, `NSData` and `NSError` parameters in that that `completionHandler` parameter.

See [Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-XID_151) discussion in *The Swift Programming Language.*

Comment: Hi @Rob so if I wanted to print the response I got from the webpage where the data was posted do I have to use NSURLResponse variable?

Comment: The `response` is the header information (status code, content-type, etc.). If you want to see the body of the response, then you look at the `data`.

Comment: do you mean NSData can you tell me the property of NSData to access e.g. NSData.text or NSData.data?

Comment: Close, but the `NSData` doesn't have `text` or `data` properties. This `NSData` is simply the binary data of the body of the response from the server. If this `NSData` contains text or HTML, you can be converted to a `NSString` (using the code in your question) so you can display it in a legible format).

Answer (score 0):

It sends request asynchronously. When the operation completed it calls closure ({} part). `response` parameter is `NSURLResponse!` instance and represents server's response. The `data` parameter is `NSData!` instance and represents the data the server returns. The `error` parameter is `NSError!` instance and represents the error might happen in this process.